# How are there side headers in the Calendar app when viewing the week view (landscape)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, header

When rotating an iPhone while in the calendar app, you are presented with a nice week view. It consists of headers for the days at the top, and "side headers" for the time on the side. These side headers behave just like headers on a UITableView, but they are on the side. Does anyone know how to make these "side headers" in a UIScrollView? The side headers must stay put when scrolling horizontally but still scroll when scrolling vertically.

I have a situation in which I need to have headers on the top and the side of a tableview/scrollview. I have not been able to find anything that is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a `UICollectionView` underneath.  Check out the [WWDC 2012 sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) on them, very informative

Answer (score 2):

This project may help you to get the behavior needed.

https://github.com/Xenofex/MultiColumnTableViewForiOS